# Move Project Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I'm new. I have a pretty stupid question like this:

- I have a laravel project, I want to copy it to another server but I don't want to leak the code. Is this possible and if so please give me the solution.
  Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by *leak the code*?

Comment: I have an example like this:
When I finished a Laravel project. I want to move my code to another local server. What I want is not to copy all the code to it, just an encrypted file or something to run. Is this possible?